# python script to share directory, added to startup via update-rd.c, hangs boot

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

OK, I searched high and low, and found pieces of my puzzle, but no solutions.

I want to share a directory over http without having to worry about apache, etc. python was the simplest answer. So I got the easy script together (called tftp-www.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
import os
os.chdir("/var/lib/tftproot")
PORT = 8000
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "Server running on port ", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

chmod to 755, run it, and it works perfectly, regardless of where I run it from.
Now I want this to run at startup, before anyone logs in, so this directory will always be shared.
So, I copied the file to /etc/init.d and ran the following per instructions on how to add a script to startup:

```
update-rc.d -f tftp-www.py start 99 2 3 4 5 .
```

At this point I rebooted to test, and the server (Ubuntu 10.10) hung during the boot process. Once I got in to recovery mode and removed the script

```
update-rc.d -f tftp-www.py remove
```

The server booted normally.

So, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Debian/ubuntu style update-rc.d and startup scripts are designed for shell scripts really and require metadata section:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rc.local
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Run /etc/rc.local if it exist
### END INIT INFO
```

Look at /etc/init.d/skeleton (present on Debian at least, not sure about Ubuntu). Create shell startup script for your program and then run it in `do_start()` function.